# How to create a customized version of a core Python module that includes C code?

Tags: python, c, json, python-3.x, python-module

I am trying to patch the `json` core Python 3.5 module to fix [an unexpected behavior](http://bugs.python.org/issue18820).

I was able to modify the relevant [encoder.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/json/encoder.py) file successfully, however the function `_make_iterencode` I need to alter should also be modified in the  [_json.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Modules/_json.c) code file (which is referenced in `from _json import make_encoder as c_make_encoder`). This C code file needs `Python.h`, `structmember.h` and `accu.h`.

So I cannot just copy the Python code file to my project, it seems I need to create a full-fledged module incorporating everything that is used by the json core module. However, it doesn't seem as simple as copying the `/Lib/json` folder into a tarball, as there are no setup nor C files inside (the setup seems to be [merged](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/setup.py) for all modules).

What is the canonical way to create a standalone package to achieve this (generically), that would include all the equivalent logic and speed-up of the core json module?

Comment: I'd suggest to turn this question upside down, and look into the various C modules in PyPI, for example [SimpleJSON](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/); and perhaps you could find out that you'd only need to modify *those* a bit.

Comment: Yes, I did start reverse engineering ujson for that purpose, but since this is a core module referencing other Python C file, the advice of someone familiar with Python packaging would be most welcome (and save a lot of time reinventing the wheel).